# How to implement custom tabs in Android like Instagram

Tags: android, android-tabs, fragment-tab-host

I am trying to implement custom tabs UI in bottom like that of Instagram (screenshot is attached). I want the middle tab to open another activity instead of opening a fragment inside the same view. 
[image]

I feel that this is implemented using imagebutton overlay on the tab host. But, I am still not able to place that imagebutton properly so that UI looks proper. Below is my code for the tabs in the bottom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0" />
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

Kindly help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 8):

Use `TabLayout` to do that.

xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:minHeight="100dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

code:

```
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());

View custom = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
((TextView) custom.findViewById(R.id.tabTitle)).setText("Tab 3");
(custom.findViewById(R.id.tabIcon)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_place_white_18dp);
TabLayout.Tab customTab = tabLayout.getTabAt(2);
customTab.setCustomView(custom);


tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            switch (tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition()) {
                case 0:
                    //do what you want when tab 0 is selected
                    break;
                case 1:
                    //do what you want when tab 1 is selected
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //do what you want when tab 2 is selected
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

**EDIT:**

Third tab is using custom layout.

Comment: Thanks Amir, but how can I customize the 3rd one (middle tab) ?

Comment: @arpitgoyal2008 Create a layout and do your custom designs then set it as tab view. check my edited answer.

Comment: @arpitgoyal2008 please consider this as correct answer if your problem solved.